Can a treatment variable moderate the relationship between the mediator and the outcome variable?
Basically, my question has already been posted here: Moderated Mediation
As nobody has answered it, I'm trying again.

Is it empirically possible that a treatment variable moderates the relationship between the mediator and the outcome variable?
If so, how could I set up the analysis?

Here is an exemplary diagram of the relationships that I would like to test:

Regarding the first question, I am not sure whether Model 1 in Preacher et al. (2007) from Figure 2A on page 194 depicts what I have in mind.
Thank you for any advice!

Not only can this happen, it is expected that it will happen, and most modern approaches to mediation other than conditional process analysis take it as a given that this will occur and produce mediation estimands that account for this. For modern approaches to mediation, I recommend reading Imai et al. (2010) and Valeri and VanderWeele (2014).
These approaches define mediation estimands in terms of potential outcomes rather than model coefficients, which makes interpreting their results a different task from selecting the right model to use. With these approaches, you typically propose a model for the mediator given the treatment and confounders and a model for the outcome given the mediator, treatment, and confounders. Each of these models can be arbitrarily flexible, including nonlinearities and interactions as appropriate.

Imai, K., Keele, L., & Tingley, D. (2010). A general approach to causal mediation analysis. Psychological Methods, 15(4), 309–334. https://doi.org/10.1037/a0020761
Valeri, L., & VanderWeele, T. J. (2013). Mediation analysis allowing for exposure–mediator interactions and causal interpretation: Theoretical assumptions and implementation with SAS and SPSS macros. Psychological Methods, 18(2), 137–150. https://doi.org/10.1037/a0031034
